# Simple array sorting program showing incorrect output

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

When I run the given program I get the output as:

```
-2 -2 -2 -2
```

The code is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int a;
int arr[4]={7,-1,0,-2};
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    a=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<4;j++){
        if(arr[j]<arr[a])
            a=j;
    }
 arr[i] = arr[a];
}
for(int z=0;z<4;z++)
    cout<<arr[z]<<"\t";
return 0;
}
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Did you run through the debugger line by line to see the output of each variable? is your school project to do a bubble sort, or some other sort?

Comment: @LarryBud it is not bubble sort, i do not remember english term but back-translating from Russian it should be "selecting sort" or "cherry-picking sort".  Definitely a case of Eternal September

Comment: `arr[i] = arr[a];` - so you just irreversibly deleted the value of a[i], it was lost for good, once and forever. Really illuminated persons avoid urges for irreversible destruction and instead move the data elsewhere. Go into Wikipedia and copy code from there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: A sorting algorithm usually swaps 2 values - You overwrite the value at `arr[i]` and its former value is gone

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are overwriting the elements. You can swap elements with std::swap:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main(){
    int a;
    int arr[4] = {7, -1 , 0, -2};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        a = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < 4; ++j){
            if(arr[j] < arr[a])
               a = j;
        }
        std::swap(arr[i], arr[a]);
    }
    for(const auto &el: arr)
        cout << el << '\t';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi thanks for all the help the corrected code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int a;
int arr[6] = {12,-3,45,-2,-2,65};
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    a=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<6;j++){
        if(arr[j]<arr[a])
            a=j;

    }
    swap(arr[a],arr[i]);
}

for(int z=0;z<6;z++)
    cout<<arr[z]<<"\t";
return 0;
}
```

or by using a temporary variable for exchanging :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int a,temp;
int arr[4] = {-6,-3,0,7};
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    a=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<4;j++){
        if(arr[j]<arr[a])
            a=j;

    }
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[a];
    arr[a] = temp;
}

for(int z=0;z<4;z++)
    cout<<arr[z]<<"\t";
return 0;
}
```